# jQuery.get() url becoming [object object] when String is used

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm using jQuery.get() function to create an AJAX request to a backend script. The script output is generating correctly, as it has been tested.

However, the initial AJAX request is giving me an issue. In console, it's coming with the URL of:

http://website.com/[object%20object]?=1567489455

I'm very unsure as to why this is.

The AJAX request is as follows:

```
jQuery.get
({
    url: 'http://website.com/backend-script.php'
,   dataType: 'jsonp'
,   success: function (data)
    {
        console.log('Questions (success): ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        self.question = data;
    }
,   fail: function (data)
    {
        console.log('Questions (fail): ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
})
```

Comment: you forgot the callback

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your url to

```
url: 'http://website.com/backend-script.php?callback=mycallBack'
```

or add the following property to your ajax function

`jsonp: "callback"`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the issue still remains. I've tried a few different approaches, including using Backbone fetch(), jQuery.ajax() and jQuery.get().

Comment: Issue has since been resolved. Thanks for your reply madalin.

I've ended up going with jQuery.getJSON(), as the issue was continuous with jQuery.get() for some reason.